# Why uniq -c output with space instead of \t?

Tags: shell, awk, uniq

I use uniq -c some text file.
Its output like this:

```
123(space)first word(tab)other things
  2(space)second word(tab)other things
```

....

So I need extract total number(like 123 and 2 above), but I can't figure out how to, because if I split this line by space, it will like this `['123', 'first', 'word(tab)other', 'things']`.
I want to know why doesn't it output with tab?

And how to extract total number in shell? ( I finally extract it with python, WTF)

**Update**: Sorry, I didn't describe my question correctly. I didn't want to sum the total number, I just want to replace (space) with (tab), but it doesn't effect the space in words, because I still need the data after. Just like this:

```
123(tab)first word(tab)other things
  2(tab)second word(tab)other things
```

Comment: A tab is not a space so awk is correct.

Comment: @Tichodroma no, you didn't follow me. I mean if I split line by space, I can't get data after correctly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
uniq -c | sed -r 's/^( *[^ ]+) +/\1\t/'
```

Comment: That's I wanted! Thank you all guys. I forget I can lose /g at last.

Answer (score 8):

Try:

```
uniq -c text.file | sed -e 's/ *//' -e 's/ /\t/'
```

That will remove the spaces prior to the line count, and then replace only the first space with a tab.

To replace all spaces with tabs, use tr:

```
uniq -c text.file | tr ' ' '\t'
```

To replace all continuous runs of tabs with a single tab, use -s:

```
uniq -c text.file | tr -s ' ' '\t'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sum all the numbers using `awk`:

```
awk '{s+=$1}END{print s}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat <file> | uniq -c | awk -F" " '{sum += $1} END {print sum}'
```

Comment: Look askance at any occurrence of `cat one-file`; it can be replaced by I/O redirection.  There's also the [UUOC](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/U/UUOC.html) Award, even.

Comment: Another nice thing about Unix how you can keep your code clean and well-structured using pipes. Of course you can use a redirect instead of `cat file`, but it's perfectly reasonable to do exposition / explanation in that form (and even production coding too), because in practice it will often end up being a more complex command that kicks things off. The performance argument is specious too; most of the time it doesn't actually matter, and you're better off optimizing for readability.

Comment: Yeah, I usually use it as a placeholder for some other process that prints to stdout when giving examples online like this.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution to getting tabs after counts is to write a `uniq -c`-like script that formats exactly how you want. Here's a quick attempt (that seems to pass my minute or so of testing):

```
awk '
(NR == 1) || ($0 != lastLine) {
    if (NR != 1) {
        printf("%d\t%s\n", count, lastLine);
    }
    lastLine = $0;
    count = 1;
    next;
}
{
    count++;
}
END {
    printf("%d\t%s\n", count, lastLine);
}
' yourFile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution. This is equivalent to the earlier `sed` solution, but it does use `awk` as requested / tagged!

```
cat yourFile.txt \
    | uniq -c \
    | awk '{
        match($0, /^ *[^ ]* /);
        printf("%s\t%s\n", $1, substr($0, RLENGTH + 1));
      }'
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [William Pursell answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11670788/4970442) , if you like Perl compatible regular expressions (PCRE) maybe a more elegant and modern way would be

```
perl -pe 's/ *(\d+) /$1\t/'
```

Options are [to execute (`-e`) and print (`-p`)](https://www.perl.com/pub/2004/08/09/commandline.html/).