# bash sort / uniq -c: how to use tab instead of space as delimiter in output?

Tags: bash, sorting, delimiter

I have a file `strings.txt` listing strings, which I am processing like this:

```
sort strings.txt | uniq -c | sort -n > uniq.counts
```

So the resulting file `uniq.counts` will list uniq strings sorted in the ascending order by their counts, so something like this:

```
 1 some string with    spaces
 5 some-other,string
25 most;frequent:string
```

Note that strings in `strings.txt` may contain spaces, commas, semicolons and other separators, except for the tab. How can I get `uniq.counts` to be in this format:

```
 1<tab>some string with    spaces
 5<tab>some-other,string
25<tab>most;frequent:string
```

Comment: This isn't really a question about `sort` (or, rather, changing the delimiter used by `sort` is both trivial and shown in the man page, as `-t` aka `--field-separator`; thus `sort -t $'\t'` would suffice to answer the whole of the question posed in the original title); the interesting part is how to change the delimiter used by `uniq -c` to a tab.

Comment: As chepner briefly commented -- even with IFS at defaults, `while read -r count content; do ...` would succeed in parsing the count from the rest of the output in `uniq.counts` with the original output format, without need for a distinct character.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why uniq -c output with space instead of \t?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11670393/why-uniq-c-output-with-space-instead-of-t)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply pipe the output of the sort, etc to `sed` before writing to `uniq.counts`, e.g. add:

```
| sed -e 's/^\([0-9][0-9]*\)\(.*$\)/\1\t\2/' > uniq.counts
```

The full expression would be:

```
$ sort strings.txt | uniq -c | sort -n | \
sed -e 's/^\([0-9][0-9]*\)\(.*$\)/\1\t\2/' > uniq.counts
```

(line continuation included for clarity)

Answer (score 5):

You can do:

```
sort strings.txt | uniq -c | sort -n | sed -E 's/^ *//; s/ /\t/' > uniq.counts
```

`sed` will first remove all leading spaces at the beginning of the line (before counts) and then it will replace space after count to `tab` character.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU sed:

```
sort strings.txt | uniq -c | sort -n | sed -r 's/([0-9]) /\1\t/' > uniq.counts
```

Output to uniq.counts:

```
 1      some string with    spaces
 5      some-other,string
25      most;frequent:string
```

If you want to edit your file "in place" use sed's option `-i`.